# Is there any way to force Segment JS client to use IPv6 instead of IPv4?

Tags: javascript, analytics, ipv6, x-forwarded-for, segment-analytics

I have a device which has both IPv4 and IPv6 address. In my rails application, the request comes through Cloudflare, and the IP address extracted from `X-Forwarded-For` is IPv6 address. But when I sent a tracking event from JS client, it uses IPv4 by default. Is there any way to make the JS client use IPv6 instead of IPv4?

Because of this issue. I see the events from same device as coming from two different IPs. I tried converting the IPv4 to IPv6. But they are two different IPs (Not two different representations of the same IP).

Comment: Does the tracking event go through cloudflare as well?

Comment: @Bergi No. It is a direct API request from JS to Segment using `analytics.track`

Comment: can you provide the information about the device ?

Comment: @TowkirAhmed I'm just using a MacBook connected to internet. What information do you need about the device?

Comment: Have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294031/get-visitors-ipv4-behind-cloudflare

Comment: It seems like it might be better to use a custom identifier for a user, rather than their IP. Imagine you have users coming from an office or enterprise vpn...their IP is going to be shared.